# Explode array of structs to columns in Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe

I'd like to explode an array of structs to columns (as defined by the struct fields). E.g.

```
root
 |-- arr: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- id: long (nullable = false)
 |    |    |-- name: string (nullable = true)
```

Should be transformed to

```
root
 |-- id: long (nullable = true)
 |-- name: string (nullable = true)
```

I can achieve this with

```
df
  .select(explode($"arr").as("tmp"))
  .select($"tmp.*")
```

How can I do that in a single select statement?

I thought this could work, unfortunately it does not:

```
df.select(explode($"arr")(".*"))
```

> Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: No
>   such struct field .* in col;

Answer (score 2):

Single step solution is available only for `MapType` columns:

```
val df = Seq(Tuple1(Map((1L, "bar"), (2L, "foo")))).toDF

df.select(explode($"_1") as Seq("foo", "bar")).show

+---+---+
|foo|bar|
+---+---+
|  1|bar|
|  2|foo|
+---+---+
```

With arrays you can use `flatMap`:

```
val df = Seq(Tuple1(Array((1L, "bar"), (2L, "foo")))).toDF
df.as[Seq[(Long, String)]].flatMap(identity)
```

A single `SELECT` statement can written in SQL:

```
 df.createOrReplaceTempView("df")

spark.sql("SELECT x._1, x._2 FROM df LATERAL VIEW explode(_1) t AS x")
```

Comment: the first solution with Map doesn't match with the O/P's schema and the second solution is similar to using two selects that the O/P already has it implemented. Isn't thats so?