# Apache Spark dataframe column explode to multiple columns

Tags: xml, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, databricks

I am currently using Apache Spark 2.1.1 to process an XML file into a CSV. My goal is to flatten the XML but the problem I am currently facing is unbounded occurrences of elements. Spark automatically infer these unbounded occurrences into array. Now what I want to do is explode an array column.

```
 Sample Schema

 |-- Instrument_XREF_Identifier: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- @bsid: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- @exch_code: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- @id_bb_sec_num: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- @market_sector: string (nullable = true)
```

I know I can explode the array by this method

```
result = result.withColumn(p.name, explode(col(p.name)))
```

which will produce multiple rows with each array value containing struct.
But the output I want to produce is to explode it into multiple columns instead of row.

Here is my expected output according to the schema I mentioned above:

Lets say that there are two struct values in the array.

```
bsid1   exch_code1   id_bb_sec_num1   market_sector1   bsid2   exch_code2   id_bb_sec_num2   market_sector2
123     3            1                13               234     12           212              221
```

Comment: How would variable length array map to fixed number of columns? Please post example input and expected output.

Answer (score 2):

suppose `Instrument_XREF_Identifier` is a column of type `array<struct<..>>`, then you have to do it in two steps:

```
result
.withColumn("tmp",explode(col("Instrument_XREF_Identifier")))
.select("tmp.*")
```

This will give you a column for each of the struct elements.

There seems not to be a way to do it in 1 select/withColumn statement, see [Explode array of structs to columns in Spark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47553500/explode-array-of-structs-to-columns-in-spark)

Comment: But that would still just be exploded into multiple rows. I'm trying to approach it so that I'll create new columns when they are exploded.